# Unable to move/rotate adequately three-dimensional ordination plot using vegan3d and rgl

Tags: r, rgl, vegan

I'm carrying out the analysis of bird counts for my Master's thesis. After carrying out a NMDS analysis with the counts, using package vegan in R, I've found that my best option involves using three dimensions for the ordination. I've then discovered a package called vegan3d that would allow me to plot sites and species in a RGL tridimensional space that I could easily rotate and zoom with the mouse. The problem is that, when I use the function ordirgl to create the plot, the rgl window pops up but when I rotate or zoom, all the lines, points and text are just smeared around. In other words, if I spin or zoom with the mouse, I start having many plots (one for every instant) on top of each other, instead of just having the plot in the new position that I want to see. How can I solve this? Being able to interact with the plot is very helpful in interpreting my data in 3D, but this way is impossible to do it.

Comment: You might want to file as issue [here](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan3d/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed)

Comment: Yeah, you may file that as an issue. However, this is something that I cannot reproduce and hence I cannot fix. The minimum information is the operating system. Further, do other rgl graphics work, that is, when you just call `library(rgl)` and run its examples?